# Использование cancellationtoken в интерфейсах

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, мой код может использовать сторонние сборки, которые реализуют некоторый интерфейс, который на вход получает cancellationtoken.

Проблема в том, что хоть он и передается, но в самой сборке его могут не использовать=> если я отменяю, то ничего не произойдет, так как внутри этого сторонней сборки он не анализируются.

Какой может быть выход из данной ситуации?

Comment: Никакого. Таску нельзя отменить, если автор кода на это не заложился.

Answer (score 2):

В .NET отмена работы task'ов (как и thread'ов, как и нормальных функций) — штука кооперативная. Вы должны *попросить* код завершиться, а он должен приложить все усилия к тому, чтобы завершиться, если уж его попросили.

Если код не ведёт себя таким вот образом, в соответствии с контрактом, то это, возможно, плохой код, и не стоит его использовать в вашем проекте.

У вас есть по сути такие возможности:

- Связаться с авторами кода и сообщить им баг.
- Просмотреть исходники рефлектором и убедиться, что баг таки присутствует.
- Если код open source, исправить баг и предложить pull request. Если код closed source, вы можете, имея декомпилированные исходники, попытаться запатчить код (например, при помощи [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/)), но это может быть запрещено лицензией.
- Из извращённых методов вы можете запустить код в другом AppDomain'е или даже процессе, и при необходимости остановки выгрузить AppDomain/процесс. (Для этого может пригодиться пространство имён [`System.AddIn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200(v=vs.110).aspx).)